# join on 4 tables each with two columns needing to join to one column on a base table

Tags: t-sql

I have 3 tables that each have a created_by and modified_by column. Those columns have a user_id that maps to a user_mstr table where I can get the actual names of the users.

I am stuck on how to get the created_by and modified_by (which can be different users for each column within a table and for each of the 3 tables joining to) joined to the user_mstr table.

```
select tv.created_by as VitalsCreatedBy, tv.modified_by as VitalsModifiedBy, 
td.created_by as DiabScreenCreatedBy, td.modified_by as DiabScreenModifiedBy, 
ds.created_by as DiabFootScreenCreatedBy, ds.modified_by as DiabFootScreenModifiedBy, 
phq.created_by as PHQCreatedBy, phq.modified_by as PHQModifiedBy
left join user_mstr um on tv.created_by = um.user_id and tv.modified_by = um.user_id
```

Just not sure how to get them all joined properly.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to join the table for each UserId, or you could use an inline sub-query for each User name which can make it easier to manage if you have a large number of audit columns to display:

```
select 
(select um.UserName from user_mstr um where um.user_id=tv.created_by) as VitalsCreatedBy,
(select um.UserName from user_mstr um where um.user_id=tv.modified_by) as VitalsModifiedBy,
(select um.UserName from user_mstr um where um.user_id=td.created_by) as DiabScreenCreatedBy
...
from ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Doesn't a join have to be done on each of these? It doesn't run without error. When I try to join I also get errors. (select CONCAT(um.first_name, ' , ' ,um.last_name) from user_mstr um inner join vital_signs_ v on um.user_id = v.created_by ) as VitalsCreatedBy The previous statement gets the following error:   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Yes, regardless of how it's written, ultimately a join has to be made. A sub-query must indeed only return 1 row, if that's a result of one of the sub-queries on user_mstr then it implies the user_id is not unique, in which case you need to also specify "which" UserName, eg using top(1) and an order by, but ideally by fixing the data?

Comment: Thanks Stu. Actually, your answer gave me another idea that did work. Appreciate the quick reply.